# Is it correct to say "Answers are more conjunctional with the question"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

I would like to know if it is correct to say "Answers provided are more conjunctional with the question" Is "Conjuctional" a word?

Comment: What are you trying to say? I'm sure it can be said more clearly.

Comment: If you say "conjunctional" (except perhaps in a narrow field where it is the jargon), then you will get blank stares from the audience.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is "Conjuctional" a word?

Yes, it's an **[adjective](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conjunctional)** form of conjunction.

Comment: Did you mean to write "... the adjective form of conjunction"

Comment: @GoalBike: Yes but I have answered only a part of your question. But What are you trying to say in first part ?

Comment: I just was wondering weather or not "conjuctioal" is considered a word. If you can answer that with the firs answer that would be cool. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: As Rahul has pointed out, it's in the dictionary, so it's a clearly word.  If it was absent from the dictionary, that wouldn't prove it wasn't a word, but being present in the dictionary is a very strong indicator that it's a word (with certain exceptions - for example, some dictionaries include numerous proper names that don't really count and abbreviations that probably don't really count).

Comment: I've never seen a more trivial answer.

Comment: I was getting errors when typing it and I can sometimes come up with my own words but, I see what you mean.